# Savon not generating correct SOAPActions

Tags: ruby, soap, soapui, savon

Savon shows that there is an operation, say

`:get_lead`, which would translate to `getLead`

When the WSDL is loaded up into SoapUI, the correct operation is given in the sample request:

`paramsGetLead`.

What's going on here and why wasn't :params_get_lead seen as an operation?

Or is there a way to manually specify the SOAPAction and prevent savon from generating it itself?

Answer (score 1):

you should use the following configuration option

```
client = Savon.client(:get_lead,
    :convert_request_keys_to => :camelcase # :lower_camelcase, :upcase, :none
    ...
)
```

You can also specify the operation explicitly with

```
client.call(:get_lead,
    soap_action: "some_namespace/getLead",
    ...
)
```